# Why should "miter" joints be slower than others?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, graphics, theory

I'm having a graphics problem on drawing lines in Flash Player, where two lines drawn on top of each other with different thickness don't align properly if I use any other `JointStyle` than `MITER`. For pictures of the effect, and for the graphics oriented part of the question, see [my post over on doctype](http://doctype.com/my-lines-align-any-joint-style-other-than-miter).

However, there's also a second angle on this problem, which is: why should drawing the "mitered" joints be so much slower than others? This seems to be a problem since at least FP 8, but I couldn't find any detailed info on what the problem might be. Is this just an ordinary bug that didn't get fixed yet, or is there something inherently slower about drawing these joints? For example, they seem to have something to do with square roots, but I seriously lack understanding of what this joint style thing is all about, technically. It just looks like some minor detail a graphic designer might worry about.

I'm asking because I'm wondering if I can do something to mitergate, er, mitigate, the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to join two lines:

- none: free
- round: draw a circle of radius line width/2
- cap: fill in the gap between the lines
- miter: extrapolate the lines and fill that

Miter is the most expensive. If the lines are meeting at an outer angle that is greater than 90, they need to be extrapolated, intersected and filled.

From the screenshots at your linked post you shouldn't need any joints for drawing a graph. Joints are only important with large stroke widths and for drawing a graph, round or cap joints should be perfectly fine.

In flash rendering miters is quite fast - it's just the most complicated join to pick.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know of any drawing frameworks that handle sharp miter points by clipping the miters at the miter limit, rather than lopping off the miter entirely?  Lopping off miters entirely when they get too steep is really ugly.

Comment: Interesting idea! Maybe even lerp from miter to cap in a certain range. Never seen it in a renderer though. My guess would be that people writing vector renderers hate miters anyway :) And the whole concept of miter limits is a bit of a hack to avoid really terrible edge case behavior. I don't think it was designed with animating over the limit in mind. I'll ask around at work about the history of it a bit. Do you have a specific use case/example of where it looks bad?

Comment: I just tested Winforms miter behavior and it works as I would think it should, which looks good.  For some reason I was expecting it to follow PostScript's lead, which converts overly sharp mitered corners into standard bevel joins, which look really bad.

Comment: Incidentally, I was just playing with JavaScript and it appears to use the annoying switch-to-bevel behavior.